# How to deal with soccer scores in entry to find out # of wins in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say we have the following df in R:

```
Premier League Team  Manchester United     Everton ....
Aston Villa               2-0                3-0
Arsenal                   2-1                1-3
```

Each entry in the row represents a score of a game (i.e. Aston Villa won 2-0 against Manchester United). How would you extract the scores to see total # of wins? (for example: how many wins aston villa had throughout the season?)

The columns represent all the games in the soccer season that they played (In this case, they will play all the teams in the premier league once).

Result DF considering the first two results for each team:

```
Premier League Team    # of Wins
Aston Villa               2
Arsenal                   1
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the row headers for the opponents (Man United, Everton, etc) are the column headers of the data. This:

- Creates the mock data
- Pivots the data long so you have the "home" team along side the "opponent" and the match score.
- `separate` converts the character score to numeric scores in their own columns
- From there you can easily compare the home and away scores (what I called them but you can call them something else)
- Finally, it groups by the home team to count wins using `tally`

```
library(tidyverse)

teams <- c("Aston Villa", "Arsenal")
manchester_united <- c("2-0", "2-1")
everton <- c("3-0", "1-3")

scores <- data.frame(teams, manchester_united, everton)


updated_scores <- scores %>%
  pivot_longer(!teams, names_to='variable', values_to='values') %>%
  separate(values, c("home", "away")) %>%
  mutate(win = home > away,
         draw = home == away,
         loss = home < away)


updated_scores %>%
  group_by(teams) %>%
  tally(win)
```